# Checking a character is fullwidth or halfwidth in Python

Tags: python

I want to check whether a character is fullwidth or halfwidth using Python

```
string="你好hallo"
for char in string:
    if( \uFF60- \u0f01  and \uFFE0-\uFFE6 ): print( char +"is fullwidth")
    elif(\uFF61-\uFFDC and \uFFE8-\uFFEE):print(char+ " is halfwidth")
```

Please help me to change this pseudocode  into real python code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check the width of the character using [`unicodedata.east_asian_width(unichr)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.east%5fasian%5fwidth):

```
import unicodedata

for char in string:
    status = unicodedata.east_asian_width(char)
    if status == 'F':
         print('{0} is full-width.'.format(char))
    elif status == 'H':
        print('{0} is half-width.'.format(char))
```

Comment: I also get a status of `'Na'` if the character isn't Asian.

Comment: @MarkRansom All Unicode characters have an East Asian Width.

Comment: It seems my version of Python (2.7.5) differs from yours then. I just double checked: `>>> print unicodedata.east_asian_width(u'x')
Na`

Comment: I also see value `'W'` from `unicodedata.east_asian_width(u'你')`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

As Alex Thornton mentioned, using `unicodedata.east_asian_width()` is right. However, it has the following returned values:

```
# East_Asian_Width (ea)

ea ; A         ; Ambiguous
ea ; F         ; Fullwidth
ea ; H         ; Halfwidth
ea ; N         ; Neutral
ea ; Na        ; Narrow
ea ; W         ; Wide
```

Returned values of `'W'`, `'F'` and `'A'` should be considered as full-width on Windows.

Reference: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/tr44-4.html#Validation_of_Enumerated

---

On POSIX platform, the quote characters (`u'“'` and `u'”'`) are considered as ***ambiguous***, which are actually 1 character width in console. For console usage, you may try a 3rd-party library [urwid](http://urwid.org/):

```
>>> from urwid.util import str_util
>>> str_util.get_width(ord(u'x'))
1
>>> str_util.get_width(ord(u'“'))
1
>>> str_util.get_width(ord(u'你'))
2
```