# How to format unicode string to fixed width?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm tring to get a beautiful list of my song info. "beautiful" means song names should occupy fixed width, like this:

```
songname1       singer1
songname2_xx    singer2
```

this code works for chars whose width is one character width

```
file.write(u'{:<30}'.format(title).encode('utf-8'))
file.write(artist.encode('utf-8') + '\n')
```

But there are non-ascii chars that are wider:

```
Cycle                         阿保剛
渐渐被你吸引                        FIELD OF VIEW
```

what should I do to format strings like that?
 Maybe iterating over all chars in a string and  count the number of Chinese/Japanese characters. But I don't know exactly how to do this, and apparently it's error-prone.
Thank you!

Comment: Related: [Checking a character is fullwidth or halfwidth in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23058564), [Programmatically tell if a Unicode character takes up more than one character space in a terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7086856), [how to control output format when chinese characters and ascii mixed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23320148)

Comment: Writing to a file, however, you can *never* control what font is going to be used for those characters. It really depends on the font how much space the full width Asian characters will take up exactly.